# What happens when The Paranormal Investigator discovers a Werewolf?

Tags: one-night-werewolf

I played One Night Ultimate Werewolf last night and the following happened:

1. The Paranormal Investigator looked at a Werewolf card.
2. The Troublemaker swapped the Paranormal Investigator with the Insomniac.
3. At the end of the round a Werewolf was lynched.

There was some confusion as to who was on Team Werewolf and who was on Team Villager. The rules for the Paranormal Investigator say "**if you look at a Werewolf or a Tanner you become a Werewolf or a Tanner**". We weren't clear if "**you**" meant *the player* becomes a Werewolf or *the Paranormal Investigator* becomes a Werewolf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegiance moves with the card, so it's always the person *with* the PI card who will be a Werewolf. This isn't really spelled out with the PI card, but it follows the same process as the Doppelganger from the base game of ONUW (the PI being from the Daybreak expansion).

> If a player receives the Doppelganger card during the night, she is the role the Doppleganger originally viewed.